# vsftp Not showing .local folders

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

I host an Ubuntu server for hosting a couple of game servers for a couple of friends. It is an intranet server so security is not an issue.

My issue is as follows. Inside my `home/user/` folder i have a `.local` folder that contains part of the game server saves/mods folder. I wish to have friends to be able to ftp into the server and be able to add/copy items. I have enabled ftp access to the home/user folder and when you login it lists all the folders and files apart from any with a `. extension i.e .local` I am at a bit of a loss and I am not sure quite whats causing the issue whether it is vsftp, Ubuntu or the ftp client.

I have included what is in the folder via `ls -la` in the terminal and what I get when logging in via the smart ftp client.

To clarify, I am asking how can I get the ftp client to see all the folders and files that `ls -la` shows. As the files I need to access are within one of said folders

Any help is appreciated

[image: Terminal]

[image: FTP]

Comment: Those are hidden folders/files, all of the .something. https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215613037-How-do-I-show-hidden-files-on-my-FTP-client-

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I feel like quite the idiot. I really thought it was vsftp. But that simple option in the ftp client. Thanks for the input. I have spent 2 hours trying things :)

Comment: If I didn't know what that dot means I would be like you searching for settings in the server side.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia If you post your comment as an answer ill mark it as the answer

Comment: OK, I will try to expand it a bit to make more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files or folders starting with a dot are, by Unix/Linux convention, **hidden files or folders**.

As such, they are being served like any other files or folders but not seen by the clients.

[This guide](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215613037-How-do-I-show-hidden-files-on-my-FTP-client-) describes the settings needed for some FTP clients so they can "see" hidden files/folders. Depending on the client being used by those accessing your server the instructions vary a lot.

For the ubiquitous FileZilla (free, open-source and multi-platform) it's as easy as:

1. Click the **Server** tab at the top.
2. Select **Force showing hidden files**.